# How can I use partial (code block) in multiple templates?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, layout, magento-1, phtml

I have a specific block of code which is a newsletter subscription form with a script. I have to use this code on multiple templates.

Currently I am using it on these two templates

- **app\design\frontend\base\default\template\fekete\Newsletter2Go\customer\form\newsletter.phtml**
- **app\design\frontend\base\default\template\fekete\Newsletter2Go\subscribe.phtml**

-

```
<!-- Partial A -->
<form id="subscribe" ...>
    <input ...>
</form>
<script>
  ...
</script>
```

Of course I could just copy & paste this code to all needed templates. But the maintenance effort would be extremly high if I would have to edit the code, because I would need to edit it in all templates.

Is there a way to save that code block and use it in multiple templates?

Comment: I think there is one way, you can add your form structure in one static block and then use that static block in multiple phtml files.

Comment: @Raj, Thank you for your input. Do I have to create that static block in the backend via CMS or in my module? I need to ship the endproduct as module

Comment: You have to create static block using CMS and then call that static block in your phtml file like this:  <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml(); 
?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a phtml file with your code and insert it in the following way:

```
$block = $this->getLayout()
  ->createBlock('core/template')
  ->setTemplate('path/to/your.phtml');

echo $block->toHtml();
```

Comment: forgot to mention: the path should be under template folder. something like 'callouts/test.phtml' in case it is stored in following location app/design/frontend/base/default/template/callouts/test.phtml

Comment: This works, but as soon as I try to call php variables from the template where I include the partial (code block) then it does not work anymore.

Comment: What kind of variables are you trying to call?

Comment: Variables which I have defined in the template where I include the partial. At the moment helpers and the customer object. I have to initialize these variables again in the partial to make it work, but this is not a good solution.

Comment: When you are in the phtml context you can access only the variables that are in block type class. In the code i sent you the type is core/template therefore you can access only default attributes that defined in core_template class. You can solve it by defining your own custom module and giving the block type of your module block class file. There you can do anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81048/discussion-between-moshe-shperling-and-black).